# Why is num::One needed for iterating over a range?

Tags: rust

Why does the following for loop with a char range fail to compile?

```
fn main() {
    for c in 'a'..'z' {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

Error...

```
main.rs:11:5: 14:2 error: the trait `core::num::One` is not implemented for the type `char` [E0277]
main.rs:11     for c in 'a'..'z' {
main.rs:12         println!("{}", c);
main.rs:13     }
main.rs:14 }
main.rs:11:5: 14:2 error: the trait `core::iter::Step` is not implemented for the type `char` [E0277]
main.rs:11     for c in 'a'..'z' {
main.rs:12         println!("{}", c);
main.rs:13     }
main.rs:14 }
```

Why do you even need `core::num::One` for a iterating over a range?

Answer (score 7):

The `x..y` syntax is sugar for [`std::ops::Range { start: x, end: y }`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html). This type (`Range<A>`) is iterable due to the implementation of `Iterator` for it, specifically, from that page:

```rust
impl<A> Iterator for Range<A>
   where A: One + Step,
         &'a A: Add<&'a A>,
         &'a A::Output == A {
    type Item = A;
```

This is saying that `Range<A>` can behave as an iterator over `A`s if the type `A` implements `One` and `Step`, and can be added in the right way.

In this case, [`char`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.char.html) satisfies none of those: it is semantically nonsense for `char` to have `One` or be addable, and it doesn't implement `Step` either.

That said, since `char` doesn't implement those traits (and hence `Range<char>` doesn't behave like an iterator via that `impl`), it should be possible to have a manual impl:

```
impl Iterator for Range<char> {
    type Item = char;
```

which would allow `for x in 'a'..'z'` to work.

However, this probably isn't semantically what we want: the `..` range doesn't include the last element, which would be suprising for characters, one would have to write `'a'..'{'` to get the letters A through Z. There's been proposals for inclusive-range syntax, e.g. one example is `'a'...'z'` (more dots == more elements), and I would imagine that there would be an `Iterator` implementation for this type with `char`s.

As others have demonstrated, for ASCII characters one can use byte literals, and more generally, one can cast characters to `u32`s:

```
for i in ('à' as u32)..('æ' as u32) + 1 {
    let c = std::char::from_u32(i).unwrap();
    println!("{}", c);
}
```

Which gives:

```
à
á
â
ã
ä
å
æ
```

NB. this approach isn't perfect, it will crash if the range crosses the [surrogate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) range, 0xD800-0xDFFF.

I just published a crate, [`char-iter`](http://huonw.github.io/char-iter/char_iter/index.html), which handles the latter correctly and behaves like one would expect. Once added (via cargo), it can be used like:

```
extern crate char_iter;
// ...

for c in char_iter::new('a', 'z') {
    // ...
}
for c in char_iter::new('à', 'æ') {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you need `Step` to denote that the structure can be stepped over in both directions.

```
  /// Objects that can be stepped over in both directions.
  ///
  /// The `steps_between` function provides a way to efficiently compare
  /// two `Step` objects.
  pub trait Step: PartialOrd
```

`One` on the other hand is used to retrieve a value from mutable iterator, while simultaneously incrementing it:

```
  #[inline]
  fn next(&mut self) -> Option<A> {
      if self.start < self.end {
          let mut n = &self.start + &A::one();
          mem::swap(&mut n, &mut self.start);
          Some(n)
      } else {
          None
      }
  }
```

[Source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter.rs.html#2738-2747)

---

What you could do is make your range a `u8` and then convert it back to `char`, like this:

```
fn main() {
    for c in (b'a'..b'z'+1) {
        println!(" {:?}", c as char);
    }
}
```

Note: That range are **exclusive** so ('a'..'z') is actually ('a', 'b', ... 'y'). Or in math notation `[a,z)` ;) .

That's why I add `b'z'+1` instead of `b'z'`.

Note: u8 is valid, only because the characters are ASCII.

Comment: +1 for your explanation but the solution looks rather kludgey. Aren't Unicode characters ordered by code points? Does rust have some function which can be used to get the next Unicode character after the current one?

Comment: You cannot implement a trait you do not own for a type you do not own. You have to own at least one of them.

Comment: @Shepmaster Oh, right, I forgot about Coherence rules. Well you could write a wrapper `UnicodeRange((1..2))` or implement a trait on a Range that returns an iterator `('a'..'z').unicode_iter()`. It would look goofy, but it might work.