# Where is the from_char() function for integer types?

Tags: rust

The char type has [`from_digit()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/char/fn.from_digit.html) and [`from_u32()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/char/fn.from_u32.html) for getting a char from a digit or from a `u32`, but where are the converse functions for the integer types (all of them)?

i.e. I expected to see some uN::from_{char|digit}() and iN::from_{char|digit}() functions (where N is 8, 16, 32, 64 or size) for symmetry but apparently they do not exist.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. What type is your input, and what type do you want as output? Perhaps you could add a bit of example code? I'm not sure what meaning you are ascribing to "converse", but `u32` **is** an integer type. Did you mean a *signed integer*?

Comment: The question is super unclear, but I interpret the "converse" in this context to be "how do I convert a `char` to a `u32`." For that, see: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_digit

Comment: @Shepmaster based on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751590/why-is-numone-needed-for-iterating-over-a-range I think the OP is looking for a way to convert `char` into a numerical value for code point, so he can iterate over it.

Comment: @DanielFath that may be so, but questions should stand alone. Future people with similar questions shouldn't need to read through an unknown amount of the OPs previous questions to understand if it is asking the question they are interested.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing @Shepmaster,  I just think we should give OP chance to change his message. I agree it was unclear.

Comment: @DanielFath absolutely! Now we play the waiting game for the OP. ^_^

Answer (score 10):

The inverses are:

- [`to_digit`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_digit) for `from_digit`: `c.to_digit(12)`
- an `as u32` cast for `from_u32`: `c as u32`

The latter is the one you want if you want the Unicode codepoint of the `char`.